# Toggle Redux State Attribute of in Array of Objects

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have an object as follows:

```
{
  "1": {"stepNumber": 1, "isActive": false},
  "2": {"stepNumber": 2, "isActive": true},
  "3": {"stepNumber": 3, "isActive": true},
  "4": {"stepNumber": 4, "isActive": false}
}
```

In my reducer I'm sending through an action `TOGGLE_ACTIVE_STEP` which takes a payload of `stepNumber` Eg. `1` or `2` or `3`...

Here's my reducer at the moment:

```
case TOGGLE_ACTIVE_STEP: {
  state.processSteps[action.data.stepNumber.toString()].isActive =
  !state.processSteps[action.data.stepNumber.toString()].isActive;

  console.log(JSON.stringify(state.processSteps));

  return {
    ...state,
    processSteps: state.processSteps,
  };
}
```

It's a pretty messy fix and I know that setting the `state` the way I do is not best practice since you should reassign parameters that way.

What is the best way to perform this same functionality?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: [Immutability Helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep spreading props just like you are spreading `state`:

```
case TOGGLE_ACTIVE_STEP: {
  return {
    ...state,
    processSteps: {
      ...state.processSteps,
      [action.data.stepNumber]: {
        ...state.processSteps[action.data.stepNumber],
        isActive: !state.processSteps[action.data.stepNumber].isActive,
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you :)